# command not working in dockeraws.json in elastic beanstalk AWSEBDockerrunVersion:2

Tags: django, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I have a small docker container that I want to ship to elasticbeanstalk
So this is my configuration:

my Dockerfile that am using to build the image:

```
FROM mwaaas/sms_packages:0.0.2

WORKDIR /root

# create a folder code where we will put our code
RUN mkdir code

# add code to the folder
ADD . code

WORKDIR /root/code

CMD gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:3000 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sms_platform.settings sms_platform.wsgi

EXPOSE 3000
```

and the Dockerrunaws.json is configured this way

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "sms_platform_app",
      "image": "mwaaas/sms_platform:{{version}}",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If i check at the logs:
ddef82a9bc59        mwaaas/sms_platform:staging_     "/bin/sh -c 'gunicor

For some reasons I want gunicorn command to be in the Dockerrunaws.json
so I removed the CMD command in the docker file and 
fixed it in the Dockerrunaws.json file

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "sms_platform_app",
      "image": "mwaaas/sms_platform:production_32b7",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "command": "gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:3000 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sms_platform.settings sms_platform.wsgi"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some how elastic beanstalk is not running the command. 
when I check at the logs I see:
67798ba99a94        mwaaas/sms_platform:staging_b68d   "/sbin/my_init"

am expecting the command to be gunicorn instead its /sbin/myinit

Comment: Are you trying to use Multi-container docker or Single container docker environment? Which solution stack are you using? Something like "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.6 running Multi-container Docker 1.6.2 (Generic)"

Comment: got it . the command that I was running was wrong . I changed and used bash script and it worked